# Trying to write a script to start a website in the browser and perform some checks

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Trying to write a script PowerShell/Bat for starting a website on the browser check True/False condition for certain parameter and then perform the action.

Plan,

Open Browser and go to below webpage,

https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/52.33.24.78

If the above page shows that IP is listed in PBL or XBL, perform the appropriate action to remove them from the list.

Can this be automated through a script?

Comment: Maybe dont use the browser for this, but the real service used for this kind of actions:

Start here: https://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/DNSBL%20Usage#366

You can see an nslookup example and go from there

Comment: This site does not perform your research for you, and it does not provide coding service to order. Your question is not on topic, this site helps you to fix a specific reproducible issue with your provided code.

Answer (score 0):

As is made repeatedly apparent on the SpamHaus website:

> **Do NOT automate queries of our website lookup form!**

SpamHaus instead makes their lists [available as DNS zones](https://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/DNSBL%20Usage) that we can then query:

```
function Test-SpamHausStatus
{
  param([ipaddress]$Target)

  # Ensure it's an IPv4 address
  if($Target.AddressFamily -ne 'InterNetwork'){
    Write-Warning 'not an IPv4 address'
    return
  }

  # Reverse the octets of the address
  $components = $Target.IPAddressToString -split '\.'
  $hostname = @($components[3..0];'zen.spamhaus.org')-join'.'

  # Fetch all records matching our IP address, filter for responses indicating presence in either XBL or PBL
  $listed = Resolve-DnsName $hostname -Type TXT -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |? Strings -match '/[xp]bl/'

  # return true if none where found
  return $listed.Count -eq 0
}
```